# CTRL-a capture not working in OSX 10.15

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, nightwatch.js

I expected this to work:

```
this.keys([this.Keys.CONTROL, "a"])
```

I have also tried the lines below, but none of these works, either. Other buttons, such as "DELETE" and "BACKSPACE", are working.
Is there a jquery, js hack/trick I can use to select entire content?

```
1. browser.keys([browser.Keys.COMMAND, "a"]);
2. browser.keys([browser.Keys.("\ue009"), "a"]); 
3. browser.keys(['\ue03d'],"a");
4. browser.keys(['\ue03d']);
   browser.keys("a");
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. Which browser are you using? May you provide some snippet in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sorry, its `Chrome v 53`

Comment: Clarified wording; shortened title.